# Can't execute Ruby file using Powershell

Tags: ruby, powershell, path, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I want to execute a ruby file using windows 10 powershell. In my powershell terminal, when I type

```
ruby test.rb
```

I receive

```
ruby: The term 'ruby' is not recognized as the name of the cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. 
At line:1 char:1
+ ruby test.rb
    +Category Info        :ObjectNotFound: (ruby:String) [], 
    CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

These commands don't work either

```
ruby.exe test.rb
rb.exe test.rb
```

I'm in the right directory. I suspect the problem has to do with PATHs, but I don't understand PATHs yet. I have been trying to execute .rb files in both Powershell and my beginner IDE, Visual Studio Code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely a problem with your path.  Try this:

```
$Path = 'C:\Path\to\ruby.exe'

& $Path args
```

---

Make sure your root folder for `ruby.exe` is in the `$env:Path` variable.

```
$env:Path -split ';'
```

Comment: @John If this fixed your problem, kindly mark it as an answer for future readers.

Comment: I am still trying to fix this problem. I input '$Path = 'C:\Path\to\ruby.exe' in Powershell and hit enter. On the next line I tried both '& $Path args' and, after that did not work, '$Path args'. Both of those returned messages. I will update this thread after I've put in a bit more research and work.

Comment: @John `$Path args` won't work, `& $Path args` should.  If you're going to try that way, use the path to the exe without quotes so it's interpreted as an exe properly.

Comment: No success yet. In powershell, I navigate to PS C:\> and type `$Path = 'C:\Path\to\ruby.exe'`. I hit enter. On the next line, `& $Path args`. This returns the following error message: `& : The term 'C:\Path\to\ruby.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet ...` Here is a screenshot of the error message: https://pasteboard.co/GWU3WEg.png

Comment: @John You weren't supposed to use that string literally.. It's a representation of your install location for rb.exe/ruby.exe

Comment: The answer below ended up working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to kill all instances of powershell -- in my case vscode then relaunch and it picked up the new path environment variables and ruby worked!

Sometimes a full restart is what the doctor prescribed.

I've also had cases where you had to run the program as an administrator to work and have the proper updated new path variable.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell, navigate to the directory where your ruby file is stored. It will look something like this `C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\Ruby_Practice_folder>`

Type

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Hit enter. Type

```
ruby your_ruby_file.rb
```